# How to calculate distance from point o filled/unfilled rectangle

Tags: c++, qt, boost, boost-geometry

I am visualising different sorts of geometries using Qt 5.

There I have a `QRect` that is either visualised as filled or not.
Now I want to calculate the distance of a `QPoint` to that rectangle using `boost::geometry`.
A point within the rectangle should have a distance of `0` when filled, and the distance to the next line when not filled.

Since the documentation of `Box` does not mention that it is a shape I thought I could use it for this case and adapted the `Box` concept to `QRect`.

The following example does not work though, since a `Box` is treated as shape and therefore always "filled".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/core/cs.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <QtCore/QPoint>
#include <QtCore/QRect>

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D_GET_SET(QPoint, int, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian, x, y, setX, setY);

namespace boost { namespace geometry {

namespace traits
{
    template <> struct tag<QRect>        { typedef box_tag type; };
    template <> struct point_type<QRect> { typedef QPoint type; };

    template <std::size_t Index, std::size_t Dimension>
    struct indexed_access<QRect, Index, Dimension>
    {
        typedef typename geometry::coordinate_type<QRect>::type coordinate_type;

        static inline coordinate_type get(const QRect &r)
        {
            if (Index == boost::geometry::min_corner)
                return geometry::get<Dimension>(r.topLeft());
            else
                return geometry::get<Dimension>(r.bottomRight());
        }
    };
}
}}

double distance(const QPoint &p, const QRect &r, const bool filled)
{
    if (filled && r.contains(p))
        return 0.0;
    else
        return boost::geometry::distance(p, r);
}

int main()
{
    QRect r(QPoint(0, 0), QPoint(20, 10));
    QPoint p(5, 5); // whithin rect

    // 0, instead of 5
    std::cout << "not filled: " << distance(p, r, false) << '\n';

    // 0, as expected
    std::cout << "filled: " << distance(p, r, true) << '\n';
}
```

Run `g++ -Wall -O2 -fPIC main.cpp -I/usr/include/qt -lQtCore` to build this on Linux.

I could of course use the `LineString` for the not filled case, though then there would be dynamic allocations.
Unless I create a manualy adaption which uses an underlying `QRect`, which would be quite some work.

How do I best tackle this issue?

Comment: Wow. The improved question is much better. (I wasted a bit earlier then). I looked at the Linestring Concept and I feel it's not worth creating a range proxy to satisfy the requirements for it. I would, instead, just copy the four corners into a `boost::geometry::model::linestring<P>` and use that. You can always "smart" pre-alloc a linestring for the purpose (just `.clear()` or overwrite the element points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relative easy way to support non-filled `QRect` is to use the `LineString` concept.
To avoid overhead of a allocations `std::array` could be used.

Based on the intial code, the following parts need to be added:

```
#include <array>

using RectLineString = std::array<QPoint, 5>;
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_LINESTRING(RectLineString)

double distance(const QPoint &p, const QRect &r, const bool filled)
{
    if (filled && r.contains(p))
        return 0.0;
    else
    {
        RectLineString rls;
        fillRectLineString(rls, rect);
        return boost::geometry::distance(p, rls);
    }
}
```

What `fillrectLineString` should look like depends on how you want to handle the issue that [`QRect::bottomRight()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrect.html#bottomRight) returns `QPoint(rect.x() + rect.width() - 1, rect.y() + rect.height() - 1)`.
So I provide two versions here:

```
// bottomRight() is QPoint(rect.x() + rect.width() - 1, rect.y() + rect.height() - 1)
void fillRectLineString1(RectLineString &rls, const QRect &rect)
{
    rls[0] = rect.topLeft();
    rls[1] = rect.topRight();
    rls[2] = rect.bottomRight();
    rls[3] = rect.bottomLeft();
    rls[4] = rect.topLeft();
}

// bottomRight() is QPoint(rect.x() + rect.width(), rect.y() + rect.height())
void fillRectLineString2(RectLineString &rls, const QRect &rect)
{
    rls[0] = QPoint(rect.x(), rect.y());
    rls[1] = QPoint(rect.x() + rect.width(), rect.y());
    rls[2] = QPoint(rect.x() + rect.width(), rect.y() + rect.height());
    rls[3] = QPoint(rect.x(), rect.y() + rect.height());
    rls[4] = QPoint(rect.x(), rect.y());
}
```

Comment: Yes. This is what I meant. Of course you can do without heap allocations (still not zero-copy).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you're right line-string is required because Box implies a filled shape. Same thing for polygons, actually, in my quick test.

> You could of course create a fake "holey" polygon that has an edge of some small width. But that's cheating and certainly less efficient

Indeed, you can use linestring here:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ae11cc6dcff1ca2)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/linestring.hpp>

using namespace boost::geometry;

int main()
{
    using Point = model::d2::point_xy<double>;
    using Rect  = model::linestring<Point>;

    Rect rect;
    rect.insert(rect.end(), {
            Point {  0,  0 },
            Point { 10,  0 },
            Point { 10, 20 },
            Point {  0, 20 },
            Point {  0,  0 },
        });

    std::cout << "distance point within: "     << distance(rect, Point(5, 5))  << '\n'; // 0
    std::cout << "distance point not within: " << distance(rect, Point(15, 5)) << '\n'; // 5
}
```

Which prints

```
distance point within: 5
distance point not within: 5
```

I don't see any reason to believe that the linestring is less efficient than the polygon (it's basically the same as just the outer ring of a polygon).

However, indeed box testing might be faster. I suggest you profile it. If it's faster, just use the box in case the shape is known to be "filled" and a linestring otherwise.

Comment: So to avoid the dynamic allocations linestring does I would have to create a linstring with a fixed size of 5, which internally refers to the actual box?

Comment: Wait what. Maybe you could share a SSCCE where you are stuck. I'm not sure I get what you mean here.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and multi-edits. I hope it is more clear now.